# How do I make my bones influence others when they move?

Tags: rigging, bones

I have a problem with my rig. It's a very basic human body mesh, as you can see in the picture

[image: There are few bones and it's quite simple]

I want to be able not just to rotate a bone, but also to move it around and still make the other ones move with it. This is what happens when I move the pelvis bone (the first bone I made, I think that makes it the base bone).

[image: It deforms the mesh but the leg bones don't follow]

It moves the entire rig (except for the legs). Is it possible to do it so instead of moving as a single piece? It makes the other bones adapt to its movement like when I move the pelvis bone upwards, the leg bones will rotate in order to still be connected with it, and the rest of the bones will move individually.

Comment: @RayMairlot ok, this is the best I could do

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of inverse kinematics?

Comment: @Yunnosch yes, I am aware of the concept. I have used them to move parts of the armature like hands and feet, but I din't know how to use them in order to solve my issue. That's why I asked